# Is there an undead related warlock or sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, product-identification

I searched for free stuff yesterday. Mostly unearthed arcana on the wizards page but 3rd party pages as well.
I wanted to download all the interesting stuff but it seems I missed at least one.

During my search I stumbled across a warlock patron (or it may have been a sorc bloodline that I misread/misremember as being a patron) that gave protection vs. undead so that they needed a will save to attack me as well as a bonus (proficiency or resistance) to energy drain or some such.
When I reviewed my downloads later to look for this patron I did not find it. So I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**Does anyone know a warlock otherworldly patron that gives bonuses vs. undead at the lower levels?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That would be the Undying Patron found in the [Sword coast Adventurer's guide](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide) (not a free supplement).

> ### Among the Dead
>
> Starting at 1st level [...] undead have difficulty harming you. If an undead targets you directly with an attack or a harmful spell, that creature must make a Wisdom saving throw against your spell save DC (an undead needn't make the save when it includes you in an area effect, such as the explosion of fireball). On a failed save, the creature must choose a new target or forfeit targeting someone instead of you, potentially wasting the attack or spell.

Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, page 139.

Comment: Right, I have that one but it never occurred to me to check it. Thanks a lot. I'd thought I remember undying but when I searched for it I only came up with undying light or something (from UA) and assumed my memory was wrong.